# How to optimize MySQL query for large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I am trying to optimize the following query as it is taking an extremely long time to execute. Can anyone provide any advice on how to optimize this and can they recommend any indexing that would speed it up. As a note the edata table contains around 1 million rows and the ddata table has around 15 million rows. There are around 5,000 items selected from ddata if you run the query

```
SELECT * FROM ddata WHERE DATE(startDate) = DATE(NOW());
```

The query that I am trying to optimize is:

```
SELECT e.ID,e.uID,e.sID
FROM edata e
LEFT JOIN ddata d ON e.sID=d.sID
WHERE DATE(d.startDate)=DATE(NOW());
```

Thanks

Comment: basic rule of thumb for indexes: any field used in a comparison operation should have an index on it. that's any thing used in your `where`, `join`, and sometimes `order` clauses. Note that having an index on a field isn't of any use if you're using values DERIVED from that field in the comparison, like you are with your DATE() calls. `startDate` might be indexed, but something like `md5(somefield)` will force a table scan.

Comment: Possibly as an aside, using NOW() means the query won't go into the query cache – if you prefilled that with a string, then repeated runs would be quicker.

Comment: I'd run EXPLAIN statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html to show you information about the query.  Can you post the result of that so we can give a relevant answer.

Comment: Remove the LEFT JOIN, because the result is the same as an INNER JOIN. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

#1: You probably don't want an Outer Join, so replace it with an Inner Join (MySQL's optimizer is known to be weak determining if an Outer Join can be rewritten as an Inner Join).

#2: Remove the function on d.startDate.

```
SELECT e.ID,e.uID,e.sID
FROM edata e
JOIN ddata d ON e.sID=d.sID
WHERE d.startDate >= DATE(NOW())
AND d.StartDate < date_add(DATE(NOW(), interval 1 days);
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for this query, put the where clause before the join, this will significantly reduce the execution time.
Secondly, why use a LEFT OUTER JOIN when you're only selecting the columns of the left table? That defeats the purpose of the LEFT JOIN entirely. So a simple join would do.

```
SELECT e.ID,e.uID,e.sID
FROM edata e,
    (select * from ddata
          WHERE DATE(startDate)=DATE(NOW()
    ) d
WHERE e.sID=d.sID;
```

In general, use the [EXPLAIN statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) to understand and optimize your queries better. Also better if you go through basics of optimization in DBMS so that you can apply other techniques like indexing.

Comment: It does no make sense to join "d" because it is never used in select list.

Comment: But it is used in the join condition. And the nested query needs an alias. So it is needed.

Comment: "SELECT e.ID,e.uID,e.sID FROM edata e" should return the same result

Comment: And what about `ON e.sID=d.sID;` ??

Comment: I am not sure about MySQL but Oracle should optimize your optimized query to my query

Comment: It's a LEFT JOIN, which means **all** rows from the outer table are returned even if there's no match. And if no column from the inner table is used you can also simply remove the join. Most RDBMSes will remove the unneccessary join, but MySQL's optimizer is not that smart.

Comment: @jbaliuka I do not think so. I've working more on Oracle than MySQL. How can you get the result leaving the where clause?

Comment: @dnoeth correct. There is no need of a LEFT JOIN. Changing it.

Comment: It is called join elimination optimization in Oracle world https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/why_are_some_of_the_tables_in_my_query_missing_from_the_plan

Comment: @jbaliuka I clarified again. What you mentioned is a totally different thing. That does not apply here. We do not know whether the sid present in ddata are all present in edata. so the condition has to hold. (That's different from employee joined with dept on dept_id where all dept_id in employee table are inclusive).

Comment: No. The edited query has nothing to do with that. The edited quey is about removing the left join. It still requires the "d" as required previously. I havn't removed that. You do not even understand what optimization is referred in that Oracle link mentioned by you previously. Try knowing that first before getting witty.

Comment: @jbaliuka And secondly, I repeat - the query written previously by you without a "d" works in no circumstances whatsoever. That Oracle optimization to remove the 'where' clause DOES NOT apply here. Read that document properly or prove me wrong.

Comment: @Ashis Kumar Sahoo: Of couse join elimination applies here. When you keep the LEFT JOIN the result is exactly the same as "SELECT e.ID,e.uID,e.sID FROM edata e". Of course you get a different result when you change it to an Inner Join. Maybe you should simply try it.